# Form1.button2.text.. is not accessible in this context because its private

Tags: visual-studio

What I would like to do is after clicking the button14 which is login it would change all the button in all forms text to "sample" I already change the class where the button2 is from private to public but I still get an error

```
Public Sub button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button14.Click

    If textBox2.Text = "sample" And textBox3.Text = "****" Then
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        button2.Text = ("sample")
        Form1.button2.Text = ("sample")

    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, Username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
        textBox2.Text = " "
        textBox3.Text = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

this is form 1

```
  Public Sub button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button2.Click
    Login.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess this is winform project.

You can change the access modifier of your button in the form designer. Select your button press F4 for the property grid, find Modifiers and change it to whatever.

[image: Modifier setting in property grid]

Answer (score 0):

Do people still write VB code? Anyway, the error message is quite clear. You need to make the button public (not just the class).

But, for security reasons, instead of making the button public...I would recommend you to expose a method to change the text of the button, after all, that's all you're doing. You can even mark this method with the `Friend` access modifier...I think it is the same as `internal` in C#?

Comment: I'm new to this vb btw how would i expose a method to change the text of the button?